# Exclude jars from target folder in maven

Tags: maven

I exclude some jars from war file but not from target folder. I want exclude those files from target folder also

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can try using one of below setting in maven-war plugins

WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

but sometimes it does not works refer [this link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html).

then You can specify specific jar name to exclude from your war file like this.
WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-*.jar, %regex[WEB-INF/lib/log4j-(?!over-slf4j).*.jar]

Comment: Hi Manoj, thanks for updating the problem. I am having different problem, i can exclude those jars from war but not exclude from target folder. I need to exclude those jars from target folder also.